# Need to share session to LOCAL psuedo server on same domain in PHP through CURL

Tags: php, session, curl

I'm building an application using a local php file that takes post/get input and returns JSON results. I'm doing this to de-couple front and backend operation on the idea that it's possible to move the backend elsewhere eventually (and it's neat because you can test backend operation using only browser and URL variables.

To be clear, I have no immediate or even long-term plans to actually separate them: right now they're on the same server in the same folder even - I just have a single backend.php file pretending to be a remote server so that I can practice decoupling. Victory for this issue means calling CURL and having the backend recieve the session, the backend can change/update/addto the session, and the front end sees all changes (basically ONE session for front and back).

The problem is that I'm constantly fighting to get session to work between the two. When I make AJAX requests with Javascript, session works fine because it's a page loading on the same server so session_start() just works. But when I CURL, the session data is not transferred.

I've been fighting with this for months so my curl function is pretty messy, but I can't figure out the magic combination that makes this work. No amount of SO questions or online guides I've been able to find work consistently in this case:

```
        // Call the backend using the provided URL and series of name/value vars (in an array)
    function backhand($data,$method='POST') {

        $url = BACKEND_URL;
        // Make sure the backend knows which session in the db to connect to
        //$data['session_id'] = session_id();
        // Backend will send this back in session so we can see the the connection still works.
        //$data['session_test'] = rand();
    
        $ch = curl_init();

        if ('POST' == $method) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        }
        $get_url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
        $_SESSION['diag']['backend-stuff'][] = $get_url;

        if ('GET' == $method) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            $url = $get_url;
        }
    
        // Optional Authentication:
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
#       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
#       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
#       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

        // Retrieving session ID 
        // $strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/';    
        $cookieFile = "cookies.txt";
        if(!file_exists($cookieFile)) {
            $fh = fopen($cookieFile, "w");
            fwrite($fh, $_SESSION);
            fclose($fh);
        }

#curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
#curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
#curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile); // Cookie aware
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile); // Cookie aware

        // We pass the sessionid of the browser within the curl request
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $strCookie ); 
#       session_write_close();

        // Have to pause the session or the backend wipes the front
        if (!$result = curl_exec($ch)) {
            pre_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
            echo 'Cerr: '.curl_error($ch);
        }

        curl_close($ch);
#       session_start();

        // "true" makes it return an array
        return json_decode($result,true);
    }
```

I call the function like so from the front-end to get results from the backend:

```
    // Get user by email or ID
    function get_user($emailorid) {
        // If it's not an email, see if they've been cached. If so, return them
        if (is_numeric($emailorid) && $_SESSION['users'][$emailorid])
            return $_SESSION['users'][$emailorid];

        return backhand(['get_user'=>$emailorid]);
    }
```

So if I call "get_user" anywhere in the front, it will hop over to the back, run the db queries and dump it all to JSON which is returned to me in an associative arrays of values. This works fine, but session data doesn't persist properly and it's causing problems.

I even tried DB sessions for a while, but that wasn't consistent either. I'm running out of ideas and might have to build some kind of alternate session capability by using the db and custom functions, but I expect this CAN work... I just haven't figured out how yet.

Comment: Just to be sure, your problem is about sharing the PHP session between two servers ?

Comment: No. I'd like to maybe consider that eventually, but right now the frontend and backend files are in the same folder on the same server. I'm trying to make sure the session doesn't get lost in CURL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After brute-force trial and error, this seems to work:

```
    function backhand($data,$method='POST') {

    $url = BACKEND_URL;
    // Make sure the backend knows which session in the db to connect to
    //$data['session_id'] = session_id();
    // Backend will send this back in session so we can see the the connection still works.
    $data['session_test'] = rand();

    $ch = curl_init();

    if ('POST' == $method) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    }
    $get_url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    $_SESSION['diag']['backend-stuff'][] = $get_url;

    if ('GET' == $method) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
        $url = $get_url;
    }

    // Optional Authentication:
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    // required or it writes the data directly into document instead of putting it in a var below
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);         
    #curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); 

    // Retrieving session ID 
    $strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/';    

    // We pass the sessionid of the browser within the curl request
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie );  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'somefile'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, APP_ROOT.'/cookie.txt'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 5000); 

    // Have to pause the session or the backend wipes the front
    session_write_close();
    if (!$result = curl_exec($ch)) {
        pre_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
        echo 'Cerr: '.curl_error($ch);
    }

    @session_start();

    curl_close($ch);

    // "true" makes it return an array
    return json_decode($result,true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the file system storage and share the file directory where are stored session with NFS if your backend web servers are on different servers.

You could also use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php to set a different save handler for your session, but I am not sure that storing them on a database would be a good idea for I/O.

Comment: I agree the DB storage of session is a bog and want to avoid it. Both the front end and backend are on the same server in the same folder at the moment and for the forseeable future. If I can find a good answer to solve the immediate problem, that would be good enough for now